# Прямая речь и косвенная одновременно

Tags: прямая-речь, синтаксис

Можно ли так оформить прямую речь?

> Он сказал, что готов решить эту проблему:
>
> - У меня все продумано, и я ни перед чем не остановлюсь.

Comment: Уточните. В печатном тексте прямую речь обычно оформляют с новой строки, но там не "дот" (или как сей символ зовется), а обычное тире. если вопрос не об этом, то нужно конкретнее.

Comment: Да, вместо этого символа должно быть тире. Как-то этот символ напечатался вместо знака тире. Вопрос: можно ли писать:

Он сказал, что готов решить эту проблему:

- У меня все продумано, и я ни перед чем не остановлюсь.

чтобы не повторять СКАЗАЛ.

Он сказал, что готов решить эту проблему.

- У меня все продумано, и я ни перед чем не остановлюсь, - сказал он.

Comment: На этом форуме дефис в начале строки превращает абзац в элемент **маркированного списка** (с точкой в начале). Чтобы этого избежать, надо ставить в начале строки **два** дефиса:

-- У меня все продумано, и я ни перед чем не остановлюсь.

Comment: — не надо вырезать. Работает alt+0151.

Comment: \- На Windows - работает. На моём компьютере - нет.

Нашёл в Справке более простое решение: надо перед дефисом ставить бэкслэш: \\-

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы не повторяться, можно заменить синонимом:Он сказал, что готов решить эту проблему,и уточнил:
 - У меня все продумано, и я ни перед чем не остановлюсь.

Или всё передать от третьего лица:Он сказал, что готов решить эту проблему,что у него все продумано и он ни перед чем не остановится.

Или всё включить в реплику:Он сказал :
 - Готов решить эту проблему.У меня все продумано, и я ни перед чем не остановлюсь.

В вашем варианте всё же есть  недочёт. Чужая речь едина, но передана и прямой речью, и косвенной.

Comment: А том то и дело, что редактор частенько исправляет вариант с прямой речью на смешение косвенной и прямой. Ищу в литературе подобное. Увы. 
Лишь нашла такое на Грамоте:
Когда прямая речь – не самостоятельное предложение, можно ли внутри нее ставить точку и начинать новое 
предложение? Он сказал, что «это неправильно. (С)ледует исправить так…»
J7
Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Лучше перестроить цитату так, чтобы она представляла собой синтаксически самостоятельную конструкцию. Например:

Он сказал, что это неправильно: "Следует...".

Comment: И то здесь прямая речь оформлена в кавычках - смотрится более-менее. Но у нас на сайте требуют прямую речь оформлять с нового абзаца, то есть с тире. К тому же среди слов автора на западный манер требуют использовать лишь: говорит, сказал. В крайнем случае - считает. А такие слова автора, как уточнил, добавил и т.д. - не в почете.

Comment: Справочная служба исправила другой недочёт, и я с ней согласна: кавычки после "что". В конце концов,Вы спрашиваете, можно ли, то есть не ошибка ли? Нет, не ошибка, значит, можно.Вашему редактору нравится - пишите. Это его индивидуальный стиль, имеет право, нам с Вами показалось несколько накрученным - это наше право.Я бы не совмещала прямую и косвенную речь, я люблю классически выверенные фразы.А Вы пишете с учётом требований редактора, пишите,как он советует, правилами не запрещено.

Answer (score 2):

> > Он сказал, что готов решить эту проблему:
> > —У меня все продумано, и я ни перед чем не остановлюсь.

Корректно.

> > Он сказал, что готов решить эту проблему.
> > — У меня все продумано, и я ни перед чем не остановлюсь, - сказал он.

Тоже корректно.

> Ответ справочной службы русского языка:
> Лучше перестроить цитату так, чтобы она представляла собой синтаксически самостоятельную конструкцию.

Да, когда точка внутри цитаты, оформленной как член предложения, это плохо смотрится. 
Но когда цитируется фрагмент не более чем из одного предложения, точка просто опускается, это нормально.

Что касается заморочек у Вас на сайте, то тут остаётся только посочувствовать. И посоветовать не принимать близко к сердцу. Я через это прошёл в гораздо более серьёзном варианте: не одну диссертацию забросил не в последнюю очередь из-за того, что всерьёз принимал подобное "редакторское" самодурство. Что-то стал понимать, когда поезд давно ушел, годам к сорока.